# Why blank result showing after browsing html file?

Tags: html

i was trying to setup the `owl carousel` in html file and also i included some files in head section,when browsing the html file instance getting blank result, can any one please tell me what there is either file including sequence problem or missing something , i did checked all code many times but i did not getting catch what I am missing, please any one can guide me on about that?

`included file in head section:`

```
<head>
    <title>my practice</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
   <link href="owlslider/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="owlslider/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="owlslider/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="owlslider/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

and the html body code is below:

```
<body>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img style="width:100%; height:300px;" src="img/dnatesting.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

becuase you didn't init the **owl** just add this line to your js

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
```

Comment: you're welcome please vote up if it was useful to you